# Добавление рандомного числа при клике. jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: table] Нужно при клике добавить рандомное число в таблицу,в следующем клике,надо этой числе добавить 1.Надо при клике на другую клетку,добавить другое рандомное число,а не предыдущий плюс 1,

```
var $num;
$(document).on('click', 'td', function() {      
  if ($num) {
        $num++
      } else {
        $num = parseInt(Math.random() * 100)
      }
      $(this).html($num)            
});
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не меняйте кардинально вопрос. Если есть еще вопрос - лучше создать новый.

Answer (score 4):

```js
var $num;
$(document).on('click', 'td', function() {
  if ($num) {
    $num++
  } else {
    $num = parseInt(Math.random() * 100)
  }
  $(this).html($num)
});
```

```css
td {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <td></td>
</table>
```

**UPD.**

```js
$(document).on("click", "td", function() {
  if ($(this).text().length <= 0) {
    $(this).html(parseInt(Math.random() * 100));
  } else {
    var foo = parseInt($(this).text());
    foo++;
    $(this).html(foo);
  }
});
```

```css
td {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</table>
```

*P.S. В след. раз уточняйте вопрос.*

Comment: а можете написать такой вариант,который будет работать в том месте,где я описывал? внутри моей функции

Comment: @TyomArshakyan, чтобы всё было внутри Вашей функции? Чуток не понял вопроса, извиняюсь.

Comment: ну просто продолжать написанный мною код,в том месте,где я в //комментах говорил..такой вариант..

Comment: все работает,но есть одно но)) сейчас в коде буду добавлять этот часть,прошу посмотреть))

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on('click', 'td', function() {      
  var v = ++(+$(this).text());
  if (isNaN(v)) {
    v = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  }
  $(this).text(v);
});
```